# Get only text in RichTextField in CKEditor?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I'm a newbie. I'm using Django to write a personal blog. I'm using `CKEditor` to be able to insert images into my blog post. However, I want to show some first words of the posts on the homepage which does not include the images in the posts. I want to know if there is a way that I can get text only from `RichTextField` in `CKEditor`.

This is my current preview content:
[image: 1]

I want it to be like this (no images):
[image: 2]

This is my current code:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
          <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.Author }} | {{ post.created_on}} </p>

          <p class="card-text">{{post.content|safe|truncatewords:20 }}</p>
          <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
        </div>

      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Post the code as `text`, not image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way to do this would be Django's builtin [striptags filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags), like this:

`<p class="card-text">{{post.content|striptags|safe|truncatewords:20 }}</p>`

This will strip all HTML tags from your RichTextField, also removing any image tags. This will also remove any other tags though, like `<strong>`, or `<i>`.

If you want a more robust solution, you could look into [django-bleach](https://django-bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#in-your-templates), a library for sanitizing TextFields like this. The way django-bleach works, is that you supply allowed tags (or use the default). django-bleach will then remove any other tags (and their content) from the field.